# Problema con select en campo datetime

Tags: mysql, sql

La definición de la tabla `intento` es:

```
create table INTENTO
(
   ID_INTENTO           int not null auto_increment,
   ID_U                 int,
   ESTADO               varchar(50) not null,
   FECHA                datetime not null,
   primary key (ID_INTENTO)
);
```

Probando la consulta:

```
SELECT i.`ID_INTENTO`, i.`FECHA` from intento i
```

Me devuelve:

[image: Resultados de la consulta]

Hasta ahí todo bien. Ahora lo que intento es hacer otra consulta que dependa de una fecha especifica y obtenga el `id_intento` y `fecha` de la tabla `intento`:

```
SELECT i.`ID_INTENTO`, i.`FECHA`
  from intento i  where i.`FECHA`='30/01/2017 02:39:07 a.m.'
```

No devuelve ningún resultado.

**¿Qué estoy haciendo mal?** ¿Por qué sale vacío si esa fecha existe? (ver la imagen).

Answer (score 3):

Ese cliente gráfico que estás usando te está *engañando* por mostrarte fechas y horas localizadas.

En la base de datos las fechas han de indicarse en formato `YYYY-mm-dd HH:MM:SS` (entre otros formatos) o de lo contrario no obtendrás ninguna coincidencia.

Por ejemplo, para obtener el registro correctamente la consulta sería:

```
SELECT
  i.ID_INTENTO, i.FECHA
FROM
  intento i
WHERE
  i.FECHA = '2017-01-30 02:39:07'
```

Aquí puedes encontrar más información: [10.1.3 Date and Time Literals](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-literals.html)

> **MySQL recognizes DATETIME and TIMESTAMP values in these formats:**
>
> - As a string in either **'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS'** or **'YY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS'**
>     format. A “relaxed” syntax is permitted here, too: Any punctuation
>     character may be used as the delimiter between date parts or time
>     parts. For example, '2012-12-31 11:30:45', '2012^12^31 11+30+45',
>     '2012/12/31 11*30*45', and '2012@12@31 11^30^45' are equivalent. The only delimiter recognized between a date and time part and a
>     fractional seconds part is the decimal point. The date and time parts can be separated by T rather than a space. For
>     example, '2012-12-31 11:30:45' '2012-12-31T11:30:45' are equivalent.
> - As a string with no delimiters in either **'YYYYMMDDHHMMSS'** or
>     **'YYMMDDHHMMSS'** format, provided that the string makes sense as a date.
>     For example, '20070523091528' and '070523091528' are interpreted as
>     '2007-05-23 09:15:28', but '071122129015' is illegal (it has a
>     nonsensical minute part) and becomes '0000-00-00 00:00:00'.
> - As a number in either **YYYYMMDDHHMMSS** or **YYMMDDHHMMSS** format, provided
>     that the number makes sense as a date. For example, 19830905132800 and
>     830905132800 are interpreted as '1983-09-05 13:28:00'.

Comment: Justo estaba escribiendole un comentario con que no se fiara con el resultado hahah ese "am" es taaan sospechoso xD

Comment: Yo en cuanto vi la captura de pantalla me pregunté... ¿por qué unos campos están bien formados y justo el seleccionado está en formato local? O_o

Comment: @OscarGarcia hice la prueba de varias formas, no entendia porque no funcionaba, creo que tambien hice la prueba como tu solucion, pero no funcionaba, y ahora que me respondes hice la prueba y funciona al 100%, gracias

Comment: De nada, un placer. Recuerda marcar la respuesta como solución correcta para que quede así constancia de que tu pregunta ha sido respondida. Gracias.